Who catches exceptions from copy-constructor in return statement (C++)?
Suppose I have a function returning by value
S f(); 

and I call it like that:
auto s = f();

If copy-constructor of S throws, and return some_s;
inside f is surrounded by try-catch block,
is it guaranteed that the exception will be captured
inside f rather than being thrown on the call site?
I realize that auto s = f(); is subject to mandatory copy elision as of C++17, so there is (at most) one call to copy-constructor of S. But is it guaranteed to happen inside f from the point of view of exception handling?
Tests in gcc, clang, mingw and msvc indicate that this is indeed so (the code is below).  What bothers me is that

it is opposite to exceptions from copy-constructors of functions parameters, that are handled on the call site
it seems odd that return does not actually transfer control out of a function

In any case, some quotes from the standard will be appreciated ;)
Here is the code I used for testing
#include<iostream>
    
struct S{
    S(const S &){
       throw "Oops";
    }
    
    S(int) noexcept  {}
};

S f(){
   
   static/*to avoid RVO*/ S stat(7);
   
   try{
      return stat;
   }catch(const char *what){
      std::cerr << "still in function after failed-return" << std::endl;
   }
   
   return S(7);// mandatory copy-elision (c++17); 
}

int main()
try{
   auto s = f();// mandatory copy-elision (c++17); 
 
}catch(...){
   std::cerr << "Exception from main..." << std::endl;
}


From C++17 there is no use of copy ctor in auto s = f();. The object will be constructed directly in the storage of s. You can even =delete the copy ctor and the program will still compile and will use the default ctor. Demo

@user12002570 Thanks, as said in the question, I know this. But does it imply that no exception will be thrown on the call site?

@user12002570 f() returns stat which will use the copy constructor so the copy ctor can't be deleted.

@TedLyngmo Yes, return stat; here will use the copy ctor. I was referring to return S(7). Will check the spec.

Interesting edge case here: function try blocks. The whole body of a function can be a try-catch block.

@MSalters Yes, it's a function-try-block

Since C++17, there isn't a copy after f returns. The return value of f is an unmaterialised temporary value, which is materialised in the initialisation of s, it isn't an object, and doesn't need to be copied to initialise something.
It is not "mandatory copy elision". The lifetime rules were changed such that there isn't an object (yet).

it seems odd that return does not actually transfer control out of a function

You can have arbitrarily complex sub-expressions in a return statement, which can throw. If they do, you are allowed to catch them within the function. It would be highly inconvenient if you couldn't.

Thanks. If g() throws in return g();, it is clear to me that it happens before the actual return. Here I'm asking at which point exactly the copy constructor is invoked in my code (as far as exception handling is concerned).

@Adrian remember that stat is an expression, and it has to undergo lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to be an S instead of an S&

@463035818_is_not_an_ai There IS copy in MY code. You have changed my return stat; into returning prvalue.

f() doesn't have RVO. It returns a named static and must use the copy constructor (or move constructor, had it existed).

@Caleth, Thanks again, but I'm still not convinced. You say "f returns an unmaterialised temporary value, which is materialised in the initialisation of s." This seem to imply that initialization (i.e. copy-construction) takes place AFTER function returns, rather than inside try block of f.

@Adrian there is no copy once f returns. The value returned by f isn't an object until someone needs it to be, in this case, the initialisation of s. The transition C++14 -> C++17 has a major change in how the abstract machine (which is what the standard describes) behaves, even if implementations stayed mainly the same.

@Caleth OK, so the rule #12 from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules still applies here, right? You are saying that copy constructor is guaranteed to be invoked "inside" f?  It is not clear from the article on copy elision on cppreference.

@Adrian you don't need that. The grammer is try compound-statement handler-seq, which matches any exception thrown by compound-statement to the handlers in handler-seq. There is a copy in return stat, it is one of the cases of copy-initialisation. The wording on cppreference is slightly misleading as it talks about objects being initialised, which isn't appropriate for the return case.

@Caleth But how do you know ``there is a copy in return stat"? I believe you are right, but how does it follow from the standard? I can believe that C++17 rules say that the copy-constuctor is invoked once (without RVO, like in my case), so my problem boils down to question how do we know it is invoked in return stat.

@Adrian It seems you've wandered off from the question you posted. I think you should see if you got the question answered by any of the answers you've gotten and then perhaps ask a new one about when NRVO is allowed and when RVO is mandated. Copy Elision @ cppreference may be a good start. You'll find that NRVO (in return stat;) is not allowed. Since it's not allowed, it must copy.

@Adrian It is basically the special behavior of prvalues. Since C++17 they are no longer "temporary values", but "initialization recipes". Basically a sequence of prvalue "copies" is eliminated such that the destination on one end of the sequence (s) is initialized directly by the construct that "initialized" the prvalue at the other end of the sequence (the copy-constructor in return stat).


is it guaranteed to happen inside f from the point of view of exception handling?

Yes.
C++17:

18.1. Throwing an exception

When an exception is thrown, control is transferred to the nearest handler with a matching type ([except.handle]); “nearest” means the handler for which the compound-statement or ctor-initializer following the try keyword was most recently entered by the thread of control and not yet exited.


When the copy constructor throws in your example, the try block in f() is not yet exited. The exception happens before the evaluation of the full-expression in the return statement is complete.
This means that control is transferred to the nearest handler with a matching type, which is also inside f().

Thanks! What still bothers me is how this interacts with c++17 mandatory "copy elision" of the operand in return statement.

@Adrian In return stat; there is no NRVO (named return value optimization, previously copy elision) possible - much less RVO (previously called mandatory copy elision).

Yes, that is why I made it static. I must think about it. Thanks.

@Adrian You're welcome!  I hope the passage from the standard eventually makes clear that the exception is guaranteed to be caught in the function (if there's a handler installed for it, like in your case). If you remove the complexity of classes I think it's easier to follow. example

The copy-constructor that runs in return stat; initializes the variable s in auto s = f();. Despite having such a long-range effect outside the function it still runs inside the function as part of the return statement. Therefore, its exceptions can be caught in the function.

Yes, indeed, I forgot to address @Adrian.

@j6t I believe you are right. And you are addressing exactly my problem!  But I'm trying to connect the dots: How exactly this follows from the rules of the language? How do you know that ``the copy-constructor runs in return stat;" in view of C++17 rules o "copy-elision"?

@Adrian There is no copy elision in return stat;.  Every full-expression is sequenced before the next full-expression, so return expression ; must be fully evaluated before transferring control anywhere. Since it throws, control is still within f().

@Adrian we know because stat is an lvalue expression denoting an object in static storage, so return stat matches the grammar rule copy-initialisation

@Caleth I don't see the how the standard text on copy-initialisation implies that.
But I found that Note in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.return#2 explicitly says  ``A return statement can involve an invocation of a constructor to perform a copy or move". Do you know where this whole "materialization" is described in the standard? The text in /n4659/class.temporary is not particularly enlightening.

@Adrian it comes from the definition of the value categories basic.lval

@Adrian "Temporary materialization" is the opposite of what is happening here.

I believe this can be answered without language-lawyering.
X f() {return ...;}
Y y = f();

This in general involves two copies (or two objects being created, rather), unless elided.
First ... is copied into the returned temporary (of type X), and then that temporary is copied into Y y.
The second one is always elided if X and Y are the same type (since C++17) (including if Y is auto). The first one is elided if you return a prvalue.
If the first one throws, the function can catch it. If the second one throws, only the caller can catch it.
This makes sense because the first copy happens relatively early, before the local variables are destroyed even. So it would make little sense to prevent the function from catching exceptions during this copy, but then allowing catching exceptions from local variables' destructors, which can be thrown after that.

Thanks. You are referring to #12 from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules and I was indeed wondering if this guarantees that exception is caught inside function. I guess the c++17 rules make this more confusing (for me at least).
